# VBA - worksheet parameter in function

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have a function 'mergeCategories' taking into argument (worksheet, worksheet, long). The idea is to read the value of a cell and replace it with another value based on a mapping table.

The content of the  function works well when I run it as a sub and declaring the values inside the sub. But when i call the function from a sub, i get error Run-time error 424 Object Required at the line:
last_row_matching = ws_matching.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Apparently, there is an issue with the worksheet ws_matching

Here is the function:

```
    Function mergeCategories(ws_source As Worksheet, ws_macthing As Worksheet, last_row_used As Long) As Boolean
   'Variables
    'Result boolean
    Dim final_result As Boolean
    final_result = False

    'Source category name
    Dim src_cat_name As String

    'Destination category name
    Dim dest_cat_name As String

    'Index of last row in matching table
    Dim last_row_matching As Long
    last_row_matching = ws_matching.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    MsgBox "Last row matching " & last_row_matching

    'Result of the matching (as range, .Value used to get name)
    Dim result_range As Range


    'Loop
    For i = 1 To last_row_used


        'get the source category name
        src_cat_name = ws_source.Range("A" & i).Value
        MsgBox "The category name pulled is " & src_cat_name

        'Find the mapping
        Set result_range = ws_matching.Range("A2:A" & last_row_matching).Find(src_cat_name)
        dest_cat_name = result_range.Offset(0, 1).Value

      MsgBox "The new category name is " & dest_cat_name
        ws_source.Range("A" & i).Value = dest_cat_name
        ws_source.Range("A" & i).Activate
        MsgBox "Check"
    Next i

    final_result = True
End Function
```

Here is the macro:

```
Sub test_mergeCategories()

    Dim ws_matching As Worksheet
    Set ws_matching = Sheets("Matching")
    Dim ws_source As Worksheet
    Set ws_source = Sheets("Temp_Import")
    Dim last_row_used As Long
    last_row_used = ws_source.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

   Call mergeCategories(ws_source, ws_matching, last_row_used)


End Sub
```

Any idea of what is the issue?

Comment: Not your problem but why are you using a function when it does not return anything?  Is should be a Sub.  Plus you are not doing anything with `Final_Result` except changing it from False to True, it goes no where nor is it used after, or before, changing the value.

Comment: Check the spelling of your arguments, and look up Option Explicit.

Comment: Youo misspelled ws_macthing

Comment: Apart from misspelling, there is a bug in your function that may arise depending on the situation.Check this `If result_range Is Nothing` in your function before defining `dest_cat_name` and skip that line in case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer , indeed mispelling here. Will update the code with more conditions checks later